A box contains 10 blue, 20 red, 8 green, 15 yellow and 25 white balls. How many balls must we choose to guarantee having 12 balls of the same colour?
This is a question from the pigeonhole principle. I tried to do it and I got 52 as the answer. But the answer given in my class' notes is 56. I would like to know the correct answer to this question. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Edit 1-: I have uploaded the photo of how I tried to do it. I didn't use the pigeonhole formula but did it manually.
Image
I have assumed the worst-case in the sense that each ball we pick will be of a different colour.

Edit 2-: Since photo isn't allowed or encouraged here, and since I didn't try to do it using any formula but rather manually and hence, can't write it using the Tex Editor, I have typed it below using the keyboard. Here -
8 Green   10 Blue   15 Yellow   20 Red   25 White
   .         .          .          .         .     1)
   .         .          .          .         .     2)
   .         .          .          .         .     3)
   .         .          .          .         .     4)
   .         .          .          .         .     5)
   .         .          .          .         .     6)
   .         .          .          .         .     7)
   .         .          .          .         .     8)
             .          .          .         .     9)
             .          .          .         .     10)
                        .          .         .     11)
                                             .     12)

First, we exhaust all the 8 Green Balls. This gives us 8 x 5 = 40. Then, we exhaust all the 10 Blue Balls. This gives 2 x 4 = 8. Then, we take the 11th turn and this gives us 3. Then, for the 12th Ball, we take any out of Yellow, Red or White. This gives us a total of -: 40 + 8 + 3 + 1 = 52 Balls.
This could be wrong and that's why I need someone to verify and give me the correct answer.

Hi, please show your work, and then we can tell you if you made some mistake.

@IvánGM I have now uploaded the photo of how I tried to do it. Please verify.

Not a photo – write it out. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@GerryMyerson I have made a new edit.

This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, typing $8 \cdot 5 = 40$ produces $8 \cdot 5 = 40$.

You are correct that we must choose $52$ balls in order to guarantee that there at least $12$ balls of one colour.
The worst case scenario is that we first select all $10$ blue, $11$ red, $8$ green, $11$ yellow, and $11$ white balls, in which case we will have selected $10 + 11 + 8 + 11 + 11 = 51$ balls without selecting $12$ balls of one colour.  At that point, selecting any of the remaining balls will force us to select $12$ balls of one colour.
